# Build parser from set of examples

Tags: parsing

I wonder if there's a way to build a parser from set of examples. Examples could be provided as a set of input/output pairs, or maybe input with some sort of annotations.

For example if I want to provide bunch of JSON or YAML snippets, simplified not full spec, and annotate it somehow and the tool analyse it and build the parser.

Are there such parser generators?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think that's a very hard problem. For example, how many different samples with a string should the generator see before it realizes that in fact any string is accepted at this particular location in the (emerging) grammar? (as opposed to only accepting those exact strings that were in the samples).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError true, but that's where annotations could help.